# Juntar duas matrizes e exibi-las em uma terceira verticalmente

Tags: python, array

Criei duas **matrizes M1 e M2 e elas possuem uma dimensão para sete elementos**. Uma terceira **matriz chamada M3 possui duas dimensões onde sua primeira coluna deve ser formada pelos elementos da matriz MA e a segunda coluna pelos elementos da matriz B**. Logo depois é preciso exibir M3:

```
input:
02 04 06 08 10 12 14
02 04 06 08 10 12 14
```

```
Saída
02  02
04  04
06  06
08  08
10  10
12  12
14  14
```

```
Código:
M1 = input()
lista1 = M1.split()
M2 = input()
lista2 = M2.split()

MA = [lista1]
MB = [lista2]

print (MA)
print (MB)
```

Comment: Algo como `M3 = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(M1, M2)]`?

Comment: Deu um resultado, só que não é bem o esperado `>>> [['1', '1'], [' ', ' '], ['2', '2'], [' ', ' '], ['3', '3'], [' ', ' '], ['4', '4'], [' ', ' '], ['5', '5'], [' ', ' '], ['6', '6'], [' ', ' '], ['7', '7']]`

Comment: Lucas, ocorreu isso porque no seu código M1 e M2 não são matrizes de uma dimensão como descreveu na pergunta. No código, são `lista1` e `lista2`.

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, a resposta é como nosso colega Anderson apontou, contudo quando você coloca a condição **var.split()** você transforma ele em um vetor.

Teste nas condições que coloquei abaixo e edite conforme necessário:

```
m1 = []
for i in range(7):
    m1.append(int(input()))

m2 = m1.copy()

m3 = [[a,b] for a, b in zip(m1, m2)]

for row in m3:
    print(row[0], row[1])
```

Comment: m2 = m1.copy()
     >>>
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: sugiro que ponha o exemplo completo, com aquisição de dados para as duas listas  - e que execute seu código para testar. Listas em Python não tem o método "copy", por exemplo - (mas  isso seria um "AttributeError", como você não testou seu código, ainda faltou fechar um parênteses na linha acima dessa)

Comment: @LucasPimentel, o SyntaxError é justamente pela falta do **)** no `m1.append(int(input())**)**` ademais deve funcionar corretamente.

@jsbueno o exemplo está completo, e também realizei o teste via shell antes para após codificar em um script para posta-los. Contudo minha versão é o Python 3.7, o qual já possui o método "copy", segue link da documentação de listas.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#functional-programming-tools

Comment: Ficou diferente da entrada e saída esperada, não há como deixar exatamente como eu especifiquei?

Comment: @LucasPimentel, realizei a edição, execute desta forma que sairá igual ao solicitado.

Answer (score 0):

As duas matrizes recebidas na entrada formam uma matriz 2x7, e o resultado que você deseja obter é a [transposição](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriz_transposta) dessa matriz 2x7. Isso é simples de ser feito em Python.

```
m1 = input().split()
m2 = input().split()

m3 = zip(m1, m2)

for a, b in m3:
    print(a, b)
```

Só a título de curiosidade, segue o mesmo algoritmo escrito em uma única linha.

```
print(*[f'{a} {b}' for a, b in zip(input().split(), input().split())], sep='\n')
```

Comment: Pra mim deixar todo o código em uma linha é mais complicado que deixa-lo em várias linhas kkk.

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O código tem o resultado correto, só não entendi porque é mencionado transposição de matriz visto que não há transposição alguma, pois as listas não são alteradas e também não existe uma matriz 2x7. Ele só quer uma nova matriz com os elementos das listas intercalados...

Comment: @fernandosavio "_não há transposição alguma, pois as listas não são alteradas_" O output do programa é a matriz transposta. A transposição não acontece in-place porque nao é necessário. Se quiser conferir, acesse [este site](https://matrix.reshish.com/transpose.php), crie uma matriz 2x7 igual ao que o OP informou e veja o resultado.

Comment: Eu quis me referir que são duas matrizes 1x7, e que você não explica muito bem o que isso tem a ver. Você afirma que há transposição e mostra um código sem desenvolver a explicação. Por isso disse que o código é correto mas a explicação não parece estar relacionada ao código, você pode argumentar  e explicar tudo nos comentários, porém esta explicação estaria melhor na sua resposta, entende? Falta desenvolvimento na sua explicação